# Ignoring gitignore in subfolder with gitignore in root folder

Tags: wordpress, git

I have a fully git versioned WordPress setup.

At the production system I want that all uploads inside wp-content/uploads get added by git via cli

But on development system I don't want, that git add my files inside this folder to git (lot of memes and crap to test modules)

Also I create a rule in the root gitignore to ignore the adding of the gitignore inside wp-content/uploads

- root .gitignore ([...] wp-content/uploads)
- wp-content .gitignore (*)

It works. But can this setup theoretically be dangerous? Has anyone there experiences?

Answer (score 0):

Best rule is to have 1 gitignore in the root.

to ignore uploads completely it would be something like

`path/to/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/*`

If you want to allow a sub directory of uploads do something like this after the above

`!path/to/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017`

Comment: I know

But on my production system i need all files inside the uploads folder to pull them to my development system. 

I only want to prevent, that testing images get shared between my development system and my production system.

The root .gitignore file is need to be shared between the production and development env.

Answer (score 0):

As a strategy, you can ignore `upload/` completely and have a script for developers that copies your test items to `/upload` just after cloning. So every developer would call, say `./load_fixtures.sh` to setup the project.